# How do I detect if there is already a similar document stored in Lucene index

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net, morelikethis

I need to exclude duplicates in my database. The problem is that duplicates are not considered exact match but rather similar documents. For this purpose I decided to use `FuzzyQuery` like follows:

```
var fuzzyQuery = new global::Lucene.Net.Search.FuzzyQuery(
                     new Term("text", queryText),
                     0.8f,
                     0);
 hits = _searcher.Search(query);
```

The idea was to set the minimal similarity to 0.8 (that I think is high enough) so only similar documents will be found excluding those that are not sufficiently similar.

To test this code I decided to see if it finds already existing document. To the variable `queryText` was assigned a value that is stored in the index. The code from above found nothing, in other words it doesn't detect even exact match.

Index was build by this code:

```
 doc.Add(new global::Lucene.Net.Documents.Field(
            "text",
            text,
            global::Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES,
            global::Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.TOKENIZED,
            global::Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
```

I followed recomendations from bellow and the results are:
TermQuery doesn't return any result.
Query contructed with

```
 var _analyzer = new RussianAnalyzer();
 var parser = new global::Lucene.Net.QueryParsers
                .QueryParser("text", _analyzer);
 var query = parser.Parse(queryText);
 var _searcher = new IndexSearcher
       (Settings.General.Default.LuceneIndexDirectoryPath);
 var hits = _searcher.Search(query);
```

Returns several results with the maximum score the document that has exact match and other several documents that have similar content.

Comment: Could you describe the problem you are going to solve by finding duplicate documents?

Comment: The problem is to find a way to detect if there is already an existing similar document in index (database) a  respectively diminish the global number of close duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to look inside the index - will clearly show what data you're querying against and how Lucene 'sees' you data. You can use [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) for this. It has some known [compatibility issues](http://code.google.com/p/luke/wiki/Compatibility) with Lucent.NET but is much better than nothing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I second the recommendation for Luke. A few other things to try:

1. Try first an exact query, say a TermQuery for the term "text". If this doesn't work, no fuzzy query will.
2. Use [Explain()](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/docs/2.4.1/Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Explain_overloads.html) to see how the scoring went (that is provided you get other hits).
3. Follow the suggestions from [Debugging Relevance Issues in Search](http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Debugging-Relevance-Issues-Search).

Comment: If TermQuery doesn't return any result? But stil ordinary search does. Could it be connected with the fact that search is done in Russian?

Comment: I suspect that using different analyzers for indexing and retrieval is to blame. Try using RussianAnalyzer for both - use the RussianAnalyzer for the FuzzyQuery search as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [MoreLikeThis](http://lucene.apache.org/java/1_9_1/api/org/apache/lucene/search/similar/MoreLikeThis.html) class in Lucene...it has some great heuristics encoded that would help you identify "similar" documents.

Comment: Yes but I also need to know the degree of similarity in absolute numbers.

Comment: 1. Use MLT to retrieve similar docs using Lucene
2. Use Cosine similarity algorithm to measure similarity. Simmetrics is a great F/OSS library (has a .net implementation as well)